# How does $\Theta$-notation actually eat constants?

Tags: proof-explanation, asymptotics, solution-verification, computer-science

**I am supposed to prove the following:**
$$\log_2\Big({1+\Theta\Big(\frac{1}{n}}\Big)\Big) = \log_2\Big(\Theta\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)\Big)$$

While I get the intuition behind it, I am struggling to write it down on paper. I understand that it is sufficient to show:

$${1+\Theta\Big(\frac{1}{n}}\Big) = \Theta\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)$$

**What I have been able to do so far:**

The expression on LHS is of the form $1+f(n)$ and $f(n) = \Theta\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)$ where by definition of $\Theta$-notation there exist constants $c_1$, $c_2$ and $n_0$ such that:

$$\frac{c_1}{n} \le f(n) \le \frac{c_2}{n} \quad \forall \quad n \ge n_0 \tag{1}$$

I think that if we can arrive at the following expression, our question will be solved; for some constants $c_3$, $c_4$ and $n_1$:

$$c_3\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big) \le 1 + f(n) \le c_4\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big) \quad \forall \quad n \ge n_1 \tag{2}$$

Thus, to go from eqn. $(1)$ to eqn. $(2)$, let's add $1$ on each side in equation $(1)$ which gives us:

$$1+\frac{c_1}{n} \le 1+f(n) \le 1+\frac{c_2}{n} \quad \forall \quad n \ge n_0$$
$$\frac{n+c_1}{n} \le 1+f(n) \le \frac{n+c_2}{n} \quad \forall \quad n \ge n_0 \tag{3}$$

I don't know how to proceed further......

One way I can think of is that **IF** we can restrict the value of $c_1$ to be **$c_1 \le 1$** and $c_2$ to be **$c_2 \ge 1$** then we will be able to do the following:

$$c_1 \le 1$$
$$nc_1 \le n$$
$$\frac{nc_1+c_1}{n} \le \frac{n+c_1}{n}$$
$$c_1\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big) \le \frac{n+c_1}{n} \tag{4}$$

and similarly, starting from $c_2 \ge 1$ we can get:

$$c_2\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big) \ge \frac{n+c_2}{n} \tag{5}$$

Now using $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$ we can get the following: for some constants $c_1 \le 1$ and $c_2 \ge 1$,

$$c_1\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big) \le 1 + f(n) \le c_2\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big) \quad \forall \quad n \ge n_0 \tag{6}$$

This is really just equation $(2)$ with different name for the constant terms, which should in theory conclude our proof.

**BUT ARE WE ALLOWED TO PLACE RESTRICTIONS ON THE VALUE OF CONSTANTS LIKE WE DID HERE FOR $c_1$ and $c_2$?**

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is a part of solving Exercise $3.2$-$3$ from **Introduction to Algorithms** Third Edition by Cormen et. al. (if you use Stirling's Approximation for $n!$, as the text suggests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me firstly introduce that $\Theta(g)$ is set of functions $\left\lbrace f: \exists c_f,C_f>0, \ \exists N,\ n>N, c_fg \leqslant f \leqslant C_f g\right\rbrace$. We consider only non negative functions.

From definition you see, that we have "$\exists$" for constants $c_f, C_f$ so you can choose them as you want keeping non negativity.

There are some useful properties outgoing from definition: $$f \cdot \Theta(g)=\Theta(g \cdot f)$$ $$\Theta(f) + \Theta(g)=\Theta(g + f)$$ And for $g>0$ holds $\frac{\Theta(f)}{g} = \Theta \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)$

Using these properties you can achieve proof in more short way and it's good to remember, that they holds as set equalities.

**Addition:**
Working with this equalities requires certain accuracy. For example you cannot write $1=\Theta(1)$ in usual meaning of equality. We can wrote $1 \in \Theta(1)$, or $\{1\} \subset \Theta(1)$ where under $1$ we understand $f(n)=1$ function. I.e. $\Theta(1)$ is set of all bounded functions, not only one constant. So we can write only $1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \subset \Theta(1) + \Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

If/when you want to add one function i.e. set containing only one function to other set of functions, then, usually, you need some additional restrictions. For example: if $ \inf(f)>0 $, then $ \forall C>0 $ we have $ O(f) +C = O(f) = O(f+C)  $

Comment: So does that mean, $1 + \Theta\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big) = \Theta(1) + \Theta\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)$ which by the property you wrote above should be equal to $\Theta\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big) = \Theta\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)$?

Comment: @Utkarsh Gupta. Write addition to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(n) = \Theta \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$, then $nf(n)$ is bounded, so $f(n)$ tends to $0$.

You deduce that $1+f(n)$ tends to $1$, so $1+f(n) \sim 1$, so $$1+f(n) \sim 1+ \frac{1}{n} = \frac{n+1}{n}$$

So of course $$1+f(n) = \Theta\left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)$$

Comment: Well, yes, that's the easy part (and that approximation to 1 is a neat trick!) but how does one go about showing the other part *i.e.* $1+f(n) = \Omega\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)$ to complete the proof using your logic?

Comment: What I write $O(...)$ is what you write $\Theta$. So I proved that $1+f(n) = \Theta(\frac{n+1}{n})$... I will edit my post accordingly to your notations.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\Theta$ only says that there has to exist **some** positive constant $c_1$ and **some** positive constant $c_2$ satisfying the inequalities.
You could name just two numbers, for example $c_1 = \frac12$ and $c_2 = 2,$
and if those two particular numbers make the inequality satisfied for $n > n_0$ for some $n_0,$ you have proved the result.

In fact, in cases where we actually have a function $f$ and a function $g$ such that
$f(n) = \Theta(g(n)),$
it will **always** be the case that there will be limitations on the values that $c_1$ and $c_2$ may take in order to satisfy the inequalities.
For example, if you find that the first inequality is satisfied when $c_1 = 3,$
then you immediately know that the second inequality **cannot** be satisfied when $c_2 < 3,$ and therefor you immediately know that $c_2$ (if a suitable value exists)
must satisfy $c_2 \geq 3.$

In your particular case, however, there is another difficulty.
How do we know that it is OK to use the same $c_1$ for $\Theta\left(\frac1n\right)$
as for $\Theta\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$?

In fact, I would argue that
$$1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \neq \Theta\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right),$$

because $f(n) = 2$ is in $\Theta\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$
but not in $1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$

Based on your comment (that you are actually trying to do an exercise involving one of Stirling's approximations for $n!$),
I would suggest that you are **not** supposed to prove that
$\log_2\left(1+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) 
= \log_2\left(\Theta\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right).$
I suggest that you find a different way to solve the problem you were actually given.